# How to locate all '0' on fixed row and varying Columns, then sum them up?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with my code, I'm not sure why it isnt running properly and takes a very long time. What i'm trying to do is to locate repeated temp, for example, 0. After locating 0, I will continue to look for any more 0 at the temp row, if there is i will sum the test1 of B3 and test1 of H3 together... it will continue until the end of the row and will be pasted at Column N or O which is an empty column. After that, will have to do the same for 100, overall.

[image]

The resultant should be like this

[image]

I have trouble running the following code that i tried writing.

```
Dim temprow As Long, ColMax1 As Long, tempcell As Range, ColCount1 As Long
Dim temprow1 As Long, valuetohighlight As Variant, valuetohighlight1 As Variant 
Dim totalvalue As Double, findvalues As Long

temprow = 1
ColMax1 = 10

Do

   Set tempcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(temprow, 1)

    'Look for the word temp in column A

    If tempcell = "temp" Then
     'Look for values = 0
     For ColCount1 = 2 To ColMax1

        findvalues = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(temprow, ColCount1)

        If findvalues = 0 Then

            temprow1 = temprow + 1

            valuetohighlight = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(temprow1, ColCount1)

        End If
        Next

     'Look for other values that is equal to 0
    For ColCount1 = 3 To ColMax1

        findvalues = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(temprow, ColCount1)

        If findvalues = 0 Then

            temprow1 = temprow + 1

            valuetohighlight1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(temprow1, ColCount1)

        End If
        Next

        temprow = temprow + 1

End If

Loop

For ColCount1 = 1 To ColMax1

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(temprow, ColCount1) = "" Then


       totalvalue = 0

       totalvalue = valuetohighlight + valuetohighlight1

     End If

     Next

End Sub
```

If you have any ideas or opinion, do share it with me.. will appreciate your help!

Slight Modifications

[image]

Now need also to consider the name.

Comment: Are you saying that the temp row could be anywhere in A? Can you have more than one temp row? Is this for automation, in other words, are worksheet solutions not enough?

Comment: @Remou ya.. there will only be 1 temp row and it can happen anywhere... I think worksheet solutions not enough.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve can be done with a formula. The trick is to keep the Cell Headers in Col O to Q in Row 2 to actual values that you want to compare.

**Formula in Cell O3**

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$M$2=$O$2)*B3:M3)`

**Snapshot**

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

> > > Hi, i remember u using that formula and typed it into a VBA for me before, i have tried and it work.. Sheets("Sheet1").[O5] = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((B2:M2=O2)*(B5:M5))") but, i cant really have a fixed column for the printed result and also the temp may not falls on Row 2...

Here is a sample code. Change 15 to the relevant column where you want to display the result. I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem in understanding the code. If you still do then simply ask :)

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ColNo As Long, tempRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the column number where you want to display the result
    '~~> The code assumes that Row 2 in this column has headers
    '~~> for which you want to retrieve values
    ColNo = 18 '<~~ Example :- Column R

    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet name
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Get the row number which has "Temp"
    Set aCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:="Temp", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> This is the row which has 'Temp'
        tempRow = aCell.Row

        '~~> Sample for putting the value in Row 3 (assuming that 'temp' is not in row 3)
        '~~> SNAPSHOT 1
        ws.Cells(3, ColNo).Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(($B$" & tempRow & ":$M$" & tempRow & "=" & _
        ws.Cells(2, ColNo).Address & ")*(B3:M3))")

        '~~> If you want to use formula in the cell in lieu of values then uncomment the below

        '~~> SNAPSHOT 2
        'ws.Cells(3, ColNo).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(($B$" & tempRow & ":$M$" & tempRow & "=" & _
        ws.Cells(2, ColNo).Address & ")*(B3:M3))"

    Else
        MsgBox "Temp Not Found. Exiting sub"
    End If
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT (IF YOU USE EVALUATE IN THE ABOVE CODE)**

[image]

**SNAPSHOT (IF YOU USE .FORMULA IN THE ABOVE CODE)**

[image]

HTH

Sid

Comment: I cant seems to get the answer.. and btw, the 0 may happens more than 2 times.. that is why i tried to write out the code...

Comment: @user1204868: It doesn't matter how many times 0 is present. It will account for all zeros or any other variable. Try the formula. I have tested it and it works. See the snapshot

Comment: oh! my bad.. i think i left out 1 bracket.. but if i want to write it as VBA how to implement it? btw Column O may not be the final area to write the value.. it can be at Column Z, etc.

Comment: Hi, i remember u using that formula and typed it into a VBA for me before, i have tried and it work.. Sheets("Sheet1").[O5] = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((B2:M2=O2)*(B5:M5))") but, i cant really have a fixed column for the printed result and also the temp may not falls on Row 2...

Comment: Again it doesn't matter :) Let me give you a VBA Code in some time. Quick Question. Where do you want to display the results?

Comment: on an empty column will do.. :) so sorry to trouble you again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8497/discussion-between-user1204868-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: i have make a slight modification to my question, now would need to consider the name as well.. hope u can see it.